# Phalcon How to change template extension from phtml on html

Tags: phalcon, volt

I will want to change template extension from `.phtml` to `.html`, but my attempts has failed.

```
$this->view->registerEngines([
    'html'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `.` before `html` file extension. Try like this:

```
// View
$di->setShared('view', function() use ($di) {
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->registerEngines([
        '.yourextension' => function($view, $di) {
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
    ]);
    return $view;
});
```

Just tested with `.qq` extension and it worked as intended.